# How to know which button has been pressed when you have a generic buttonclicked event?

Tags: c#, xaml

I havent been able to think of the right wording for this question so apologies if its confusing.

I'm writing a program that will give a user an ability to send hex commands over serial for a number of custom object types. 
I have 8 buttons on the XAML menu page each one representing each object and I have my C# buttonclick event that does its thing when one of the buttons is clicked but I need to be able to know which button is clicked without having to write a method of each individual button. 
This is due to the user having the ability to create additional buttons dynamically.

How can I tell the buttonclicked event which of the buttons (1-8 etc) has been pressed?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <Button Content="Button!" Click="OnButtonClick" Command="{Binding WhateverCommand}" />

 private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Button b = e.Source as Button;  //Here you can get which button is clicked
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from David is one possible solution. But I'm not sure what you are doing then? What should happen then? Is it depends on Button Name (Content), or something else?

Without knowing your exactly problem I would nevertheless prefer the MVVM pattern based solution.

I would do an ObservableCollection of SomeActionViewModel which have a ICommand property and bind that property in XAML-Template `Command={Binding MyCommand}`. I whould bind the ObservableCollection to some ItemsControl and template it to display buttons

Here is a similar problem with MVVM example
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2cf2757c-e2a1-4b93-b130-6d900b1359ea/how-to-bind-a-different-command-to-each-dynamic-button-in-c?forum=wpf